# Ruby hash with string in Keys and an Array in Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

Hi i'am new in ruby and i want to get a Hash with string in keys and an Array in value, like  this :

```
Hash = new HashMap
for (issue :is)
 Hash.add(is.user_name)
  if(hash.contains(is.user_name)) then
    hash.value.add(is)
   end
end
```

to get a result like this :

```
{"jane"[issue123,issue234,issue345]; "mike" [issue333,issue444,issue555]; "Alain" [issue876,issue987,issue356] }
```

jane have [issue123,issue234,issue345]

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like below:

```
result = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }

issues.each do |issue|
  result[issue.user_name].push issue  
end
```